# AWS SDK Dynamodb query operation on secondary index with encrypted data

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to use DynamodbMapper to query data using gsi.

```
    HashMap<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<>();
    eav.put(":v1", new AttributeValue().withS(employee.getDepartment()));
    eav.put(":v2", new AttributeValue().withS(employee.getContactId()));

    DynamoDBQueryExpression<Employee> queryExpression =
            new DynamoDBQueryExpression()
                    .withIndexName("DepartmentContactId-index")
                    .withKeyConditionExpression("Department = :v1 and contactId = :v2")
                    .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav)
                    .withConsistentRead(false);

     List<Employee> items =
                dynamoDBMapper.query(Employee.class, queryExpression);
```

I am getting bad signature exception. 
PS: one of the field(column) in Employee table in dynamodb is encrypted using AWSKMS. I have configured the same KMS key in dynamodb mapper but still getting the same issue. Any pointers?

Mapper class -->

```
package com.test.model;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.*;
importcom.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.encryption.DoNotEncrypt;

import static com.test.util.Constants.*;

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Employee")
public class Employee {
private String id;
private String department;
private String contactId;
private RulesData rulesData;

// Partition Key
@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = ID)
@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@DoNotEncrypt
@DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = DEPARTMENT)
public String getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

public void setDepartment(String department) {
    this.department = department;
}

@DoNotEncrypt
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = CONTACT_ID)
public String getContactId() {
    return contactId;
}

public void setContactId(String contactId) {
    this.contactId = contactId;
}



@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = DATA)
public RulesData getRulesData() {
    return rulesData;
}

public void setRulesData(RulesData rulesData) {
    this.rulesData = rulesData;
}
```

}

Comment: can you show the mapper config?

Comment: Strange, if I insert the new record and retrieve this new record, it works fine. But If I try to retrieve an existing record it fails with the Bad Signature exception.

Comment: What type of projection does your index have?

Answer (score 2):

If you set the projection type of the global secondary index(GSI) to be other than ALL, then the signature attribute will not be in the GSI .

Thus, if you require only unencrypted fields from your query on the GSI, use a new DynamoDBMapper without an AttributeEncryptor.

If you require encrypted fields too, set the projection type of the GSI to be ALL.